# Handle unseen values when Encoding / Transforming with sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

what do the encoders/transformers do if there is a new value that is outside the standard normalized range ?

As new values can occur in production data.

E.g. the min-max-scaler

Comment: Why ask such a question in a verbal and theoretical manner, instead of putting together a simple [MCVE] to see for yourself, and then post here any *specific* questions you may have with the results?

Answer (score 0):

Every encoder/transformer handles the unseen values / outside the training data range values differently.

Specifically for `MinMaxScaler` it will give values outside the (0, 1) range.

The Documentation example:

```py
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
>>> data = [[-1, 2], [-0.5, 6], [0, 10], [1, 18]]
>>> scaler = MinMaxScaler()
>>> print(scaler.fit(data))
MinMaxScaler()
>>> print(scaler.data_max_)
[ 1. 18.]
>>> print(scaler.transform(data))
[[0.   0.  ]
 [0.25 0.25]
 [0.5  0.5 ]
 [1.   1.  ]]
>>> print(scaler.transform([[2, 2]]))
[[1.5 0. ]]
```

you could see that `2` is outside the range for first feature, hence it scales how much it is outside the range (learned from training data) and gives you an appropriate value.

Refer [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-all-scaling-py) to understand more about the different preprocessing techniques.